# EU citizen applying for British citizenship. Self employed and not sure how to prove it

Tags: uk-citizenship

What is the best proof of my self employed periods of work for Home Office? I have been self employed for 9 months out of five years that is needed for your employment history and am not sure what is the best proof of my employment for Home Office? Bank statements? Inland revenue papers showing my registration as Sole trader? Pay slips from umbrella agencies I worked under? Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you were self employed, you must have had to file a Self Assessment(s). Do you have copies of those? Get in touch with HMRC if you have to. Also, do you have PR right now, as in the a physical document confirming that? This is absolutely necessary to even apply.